# submit to ninja form programmatically

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I've been researching for days and all I want to be able to do is create entries in the ninja form admin listings. Either by submitting custom form (not ninja form generated) or just calling a hook and passing data (data will match actual form fields created in ninja form).

I want to be able to do this so that I can create any type of form layout and still be able to submit to ninja form entry. Or if anyone has any other information on a plugin that can allow me to do such a thing, please share.

Answer (score 6):

**In NinjaForms version 3**, you probably want to look at this file:

`ninja-forms/includes/Actions/Save.php`

The `process` function contains the important bits that may help you:

```
$sub = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->sub()->get();

foreach($fields as $field_id => $field_value){
    $sub->update_field_value( $field_id, $field_value );
}

$sub->save();
```

**In NinjaForms version 2**, it is a little different

```
$sub_id = Ninja_Forms()->subs()->create( $form_id );

foreach( $form_fields as $field_id => $value ) {

    Ninja_Forms()->sub( $sub_id )->add_field( $field_id, $value );
}
```

Where the $form_fields array would look like:

```
$form_fields = array(

    $fiel_id_1 => $value_1,
    $fiel_id_2 => $value_2,
    ...

);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I just wanted to add that if you want to get the submission ID after calling `$sub->save()` you can use `$entry_id = $sub->get_id();`

Comment: I know it's been a couple years since this was poster but I wanted to say thanks because this was crucial in getting a Gatsby form talking to the Ninja Forms plugin on the back end.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is is quite a while after the last comment on this post, but it should be noted that if you submit the form this way you will not be able to trigger any notifications. I have spent hours upon hours trying to include different classes and functions and try to rewrite the notifications class locally in my webhook script that was processing my forms, but I can't get it to work. Maybe there is someone smarter than me that can figure it out or maybe one day Ninja Forms will properly build out this functionality in their API. But for right now, if you need notifications this is not a full solution.

I would recommend switching over to Gravity Forms if you are still early enough in your project. Their API does have a `submit_form()` function that also triggers notifications and action steps. I just wish they would spend some time on their absolutely atrocious interface. I hate everything about their admin UX, but for more complex development things like this, they really are the best option.

[Documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#submit-form)

Comment: Good luck, NinjaForms is HORRIBLE. The documentation is garbage, and now they've merged with Caldera Forms which pretty much breaks everything. In fact, everytime they update the plugin it breaks something.