# Programmatically send Ninja Forms notification

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, ninja-forms

I've been searching for quite a while now but still can't find anything, even in the Ninja Forms documentation codex.

I am custom submitting my ninja form based on the solution found here: [submit to ninja form programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853980/submit-to-ninja-form-programmatically)

The problem with this solution is that no notifications get sent after the submission.

How can I solve this by using the Ninja Forms object and/or its Email/Notification actions?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you never found a solution for this and neither did anyone else based on the lack of ANY comments.

I have just spent hours upon hours trying to include different classes and functions and try to rewrite the notifications class locally in my webhook script that was processing my forms, but I can't get it to work. Maybe there is someone smarter than me that can figure it out or maybe one day Ninja Forms will properly build out this functionality in their API. But for right now, if you need notifications then the option provided in the linked to SO answer is not a full solution.

I just commented on that post as well, but I would recommend switching over to Gravity Forms if you are still early enough in your project. Their API does have a `submit_form()` function that also triggers notifications and action steps. I just wish they would spend some time on their absolutely atrocious interface. I hate everything about their admin UX, but for more complex development things like this, they really are the best option.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#submit-form